# Can you explain me the correct way to pass the Value? (Array to

Tags: variables, autohotkey

I can't figure out why it doesn't pass the value Correctly. The output shall be word2

```
 f12::
    target = 1
    string := "word1|word2|word3"
    S_Array := StrSplit(string, "|")
    string output = S_Array[target]
    MsgBox % "Output:" output
    return
```

when I use

```
MsgBox % "Output:" S_Array[target]
```

Instead of everything is fine. But I need to store it to output. I'm Trying for A long time now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to familiar with "**Expression style**" of AutoHotkey, that is quite dirty/confusing.

And, AutoHotkey's index is OneBased **Not** ZeroBased, again confusing.

Lastly, there is no needed "**Type**" keyword in AutoHotkey

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of : `string output = S_Array[target]`

Did you tried : `output := S_Array[target]`

Also, you might like to read : https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Arrays.htm